# How to send uploaded file as a link in entityform submission

Tags: entities

I am using entityform for getting the user details. The entityform also contains a file field where user uploads resume. After the submission user gets the submitted form via email.

How to send the link of the uploaded file in an email to user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the mail?

You can try using https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail and just insert the image in your mail